# Using jquery post request to same page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to send the value "hi" to the php variable "text" via a post request made to the current page.

jquery

```
$.post("", "hi");
```

php

```
if (isset($_POST['POST'])) {
  $text = $_POST['POST'];
}
```

Comment: Yo dawg I heard you like posts...so I put a POST in you`r $_POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS:

```
$.post("", {data:"hi"},function(data){

});
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
  $text = $_POST['data'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$.post("", "text=hi");// You have to pass "key=value" pairs
```

In PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
  $text = $_POST['text']; //$text will contain 'hi'
}
```